# How To Remove/Uninstall PHP in RHEL4

Tags: linux, php, redhat, php5, uninstall

i wanna ask how to remove/uninstall php5 from my RHEL4
i've install it, using

> ```
> # ./configure
> # make
> # make install
> ```

i've tried

> #make uninstall

but there's following error, i've tried it in following Folder when installed it

the error is looking like this :

> make : *** No Rule to make target 'uninstall'. Stop.

anyone can help me?

Regards

Why

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @ghm1014 i need to uninstall it because in my LINUX GUI it's reads PHP4 by system, but when i'm using 'php -v' in terminal linux it reads PHP5.so i wanna remove PHP5

Answer (score 1):

Removing a package built and installed from source is not an easy task. Usually, these packages come with a make file which enables you to build and install them. If you did not find any option like `make uninstall` (which is most likely), then you need to remove it manually!

If you still need to remove it, you can follow what the `make install` command does and run the necessary commands to reverse its changes.

Comment: if I reverse to change it, it will be remove all the PHP5 packages?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use whereis to locate all php related files, and then rm all of them. Unless you kept track of all your configure options (i.e. if you changed the prefix or config file location), then this is one of the only ways I know...

What I would do:

```
1. Backup your system
2. #whereis php
3. With great care not to delete something that doesn't belong to php, use rm -rf to remove anything the whereis command found.
4. Reload your environment (logout/login)
5. Try to run php, should tell you it's gone
```